# How to case text array elements automatically?

Tags: postgresql, array, cast

According to [PostgreSQL documentation on the ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

> By default, the array element type is the common type of the member
> expressions, determined using the same rules as for UNION or CASE
> constructs (see Section 10.5). **You can override this by explicitly
> casting the array constructor to the desired type, for example**:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,22.7]::integer[];
  array
----------
 {1,2,23}
(1 row)
```

This works for converting elements to integers, and for simple types:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ 'name', 1]::text[];
  array   
----------
 {name,1}
(1 row)
```

But the casting does not seem to work for complex elements such as array elements:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ 'name', 1, ARRAY['world']]::text[];
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "name"
LINE 1: SELECT ARRAY[ 'name', 1, ARRAY['world']]::text[];
                      ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

My question is:

*Is there a way to make automatic conversion work for `text[]`?*

(i.e. make the above conversion work without having to write `SELECT ARRAY[ 'name'::text, 1::text, ARRAY['world']::text];`)

Comment: Not only does this fail with array constructors mixing arrays and scalar values as elements, but also with array constructors whose elements are all arrays but of [different dimensions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5b91c64df77c7ecfb4c00628f34e1cd). These two requirements – that an array constructor must produce a rectangular array, and that the elements must be either all scalar or all arrays – are probably checked before applying the type casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PostgreSQL 14, it seems that automatic type conversion does not work if it has an array element. The array element has to be explicitly converted to text:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ 'name', 1, ARRAY['world']::text]::text[];
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Custom a convert function

You can create a convert function that is used to cast `text[]` to `integer[]`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_text_array_to_int_array(text[])
RETURNS integer[] AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT CAST(unnest($1) AS integer));
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Let's test this function:

```
psql# select pg_typeof(convert_text_array_to_int_array(array['123','456']::text[]));
 pg_typeof
-----------
 integer[]
```

### 2. Alter table column with the custom function.

Let's assume that we have a column named as `response_codes text[]`.

Now we need to alter its type to `integer[]` as following steps.

```
-- drop the old default typed value(important!!!!)
ALTER TABLE monitor_apis ALTER COLUMN response_codes DROP DEFAULT;

-- Alter table column with the convert function above.
ALTER TABLE monitor_apis ALTER COLUMN response_codes TYPE integer[] USING convert_text_array_to_int_array(response_codes);

-- reset its default typed value.
ALTER TABLE monitor_apis ALTER COLUMN response_codes SET DEFAULT '{}'::integer[];
```